# Remove nodes from Gatsby

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I'm using a plugin that automatically creates nodes for me from an API request. It's working well, but it returns more data than I need, including nodes that aren't relevant for my application. How can I remove nodes while I'm in `onCreateNode` in `gatsby-node`?

For example. I only want to have nodes with titles. If it has a title, I want to keep it, and add a field. If it doesn't, I would like to remove it. This is correctly recognizing the node types:

```
if(node.internal.type === `community_education__classes` && node.title && node.title._t) {
  const correctedClassObject = classCorrector(node.content._t);
  createNodeField({
    node,
    name: `className`,
    value: node.title._t,
  });
}
```

So I can find the nodes I want to remove like this

```
if(node.internal.type === `community_education__classes` && (!node.title || !node.title._t)) {
  // need code to delete node that matched these conditions
}
```

I'm hoping there is a Gatsby API for this that I just can't find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Gatsby's [`deleteNode`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/bound-action-creators/#deleteNode), which is part of `actions` fka `boundActionCreators`.

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, boundActionCreators }) => {
  const { deleteNode } = boundActionCreators;

  // Check the node, delete if true.
  if (condition) {
    deleteNode(node);
  }
}
```

Comment: Passing `node.id` to `deleteNode` is now deprecated. Just pass it `node`.

Comment: This caused problems for me. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55852900

Answer (score 0):

Note that the deleteNode API can now only be used to delete nodes of the type owned by the calling plugin. (https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/13600 has more discussion.)

This means it's no longer especially useful for removing nodes.