# Getting error upon deleting gatsby node of a type owned by another plugin

Tags: gatsby

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: The plugin "default-site-plugin" deleted a node of a type owned by another plugin.
            The node type "community_education__district_classes" is owned by "gatsby-source-apiserver".
```

I know I am getting this error because I am using `gatsby-source-apiserver` and it returns nodes that I don't want. I filter them out and use `deleteNode` to remove them. It was working, and still is working, but I just recently upgraded my npm packages and now I am getting this error.

Is there a way to remove this error? Is it a bad idea for me to be removing these nodes where I am in `gatsby-node.js` if they are automatically generated by the plugin? Is GraphQL the better solution for this? It seems like the alternative of editing the node module for my custom needs isn't a great solution either.

The specific code is something like this, but the logic is more complex (which is why I have opted not to add all of the nodes and then use GraphQL for filtering).

```js
if (!node.isValid) {
  deleteNode({ node });
}
```

Comment: How are you managing the node creation? Do you do that in your gatsby-node.js file or is it automatic in the plugins? I've never encountered that error but I might have ways around it if it is clear how you are deleting nodes

Comment: `gatsby-source-apiserver` automatically generates nodes within the plugin itself. I am using `deleteNode` within `gatsby-node.js`

Comment: Ok. It might help others to post that segment of your gatsby-node.js file

Comment: The code is relatively complex, and I'm not sure how much it adds clarity, so I added some pseudo-code as an example.

Comment: Sure. Just saying. People on this site tend to ask for source code either way. Many just hit the back button if there's nothing to review.

Comment: This is the result of a new PR that was merged yesterday, gatsby understandably wants to build wall between plugins, though I feel like `site-default-plugin` should be able to do whatever it wants. Can you suppress this unwanted node somewhere else? Is it essential that this node should be deleted?

Comment: I can't suppress the node without altering the node module `gatsby-source-apiserver` that creates it. Editing that source code within the package seems like it wouldn't be best practice?

Comment: oh no definitely not. I meant more like filtering them out in graphql query. if those unwanted nodes absolutely need to be removed, perhaps you can roll your own source plugin for that api?

Comment: Yeah, the filtering is relatively complex and logic heavy, which is why I haven't done it with GraphQL, and recreating the source plugin feels like a lot of work when it was already working yesterday, but that might be the only option at this point. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question as a GitHub issue as well, and the answer seems to be, "Yes, this is a bad idea." I refactored my code to use GraphQL to filter out the unwanted nodes.

GitHub Issue Thread:
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/13600#issuecomment-486413760